# Shrink root filesystem partition ext4 NVME SSD live?

Tags: partitioning, resize, gnome-disk-utility

There are hundreds of similar questions to this when I google it, but none seem to match up exactly with what I hope to do. So, Unbuntu 20.04, a 1TB NVME SSD with a 500MB FAT32 /boot/efi Partition 1, and an EXT4 Partition 2 mounted at Filesystem Root filling up the remainder of the drive. Only 3% of Partition 2 is in use. I'd like to shrink Partition 2 to something a bit more reasonable -- like 100GB -- so when I create an .iso of the filesystem for rescue purposes it's not absurdly large. gnome-disk-utility seems willing to let me shrink Partition 2 and I am tempted to just let it take a swing at it. But this PC is running 24/7 as part of an FM radio broadcast air chain so I hope not to bork it or have to reboot it. I have backed up the target machine's home directory. Thank you.

Comment: You want to resize the main system partition while the machine is running and not have to deal with reboots? Yeah … that’s not recommended. File systems don’t like being treated like PlayDoh 

Comment: Ah, very good! Thank you for the information. I'll approach this project differently.

Comment: If you make a backup with something like Clonezilla it will not be absurdly large. The size of the backup will be more reflective of the used space, not the size of the partition